# C++ | overload operator << | std::map

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, operator-overloading, const-iterator

I'm trying to overload operator << of a map within a struct, but getting a compilation error:

> no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const int, int>>" to "std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int>>" exists

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const map<int, int>& neighbors)
{
    string res;
    map<int, int>::iterator it = neighbors.begin();
    stringstream ss;

    while (it != neighbors.end())
    {
        ss << "[id: " << it->first << " cost: " << it->second << "] ";
        it++;
    }
    return os << ss;
}
```

How do I correctly get a reference to the iterator of the map? I can only use C++ 98.

This is my complete code

```
#pragma once

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct LSA
{
    int id;
    int seqNum;
    map <int, int> neighbors;

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const LSA& lsa);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const map<int, int>& neighbors);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const LSA& lsa)
{
    return os << "[id: " << lsa.id << " seqNum: " << lsa.seqNum << " (" << lsa.neighbors.size() << " neighbors)";
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const map<int, int>& neighbors)
{
    string res;
    map<int, int>::iterator it = neighbors.begin();
    stringstream ss;

    while (it != neighbors.end())
    {
        ss << "[id: " << it->first << " cost: " << it->second << "] ";
        it++;
    }
    return os << ss;
}
```

Comment: Try using `map<int, int>::const_iterator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `const` map, hence `begin` returns a `const_iterator`, not an `iterator`.  There is no defined `operator<<` to accept `stringstream` as a second argument, hence use its member function `str`, as follows

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const map<int, int>& neighbors)
{
    string res;
    map<int, int>::const_iterator it = neighbors.cbegin();
    stringstream ss;

    while (it != neighbors.end())
    {
        ss << "[id: " << it->first << " cost: " << it->second << "] ";
        it++;
    }
    return os << ss.str();
}
```